# Common Pandas approaches to adding a new column and finding percentage of group total

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transform, calculated-columns

Steadily shifting my tasks from excel to pandas, what are some common methods used when creating a new column that relies on a grouping and a value of two other columns?

In excel this could be done with a =B2/SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2) -- are there similarly easy approaches in pandas? I've tried .transform but had no luck.

Example below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'GROUP': 1, 'VALUE': 3},
        {'GROUP': 1, 'VALUE': 3},
        {'GROUP': 1, 'VALUE': 4},
        {'GROUP': 2, 'VALUE': 2},
        {'GROUP': 2, 'VALUE': 2},
        {'GROUP': 2, 'VALUE': 6}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['PERC_TOTAL'] = df['VALUE'] / df['VALUE'].sum() 

#df['GRP_PERC_TOTAL'] = ??? idx 0 and 1 would equal 0.30 idx 2 would equal .40
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gropuby-transform` strategy should be on the right track:

```
df['GRP_PERC_TOTAL'] = df["VALUE"] / df.groupby("GROUP")["VALUE"].transform("sum")
```

**Result**

```
print(df)
   GROUP  VALUE  PERC_TOTAL  GRP_PERC_TOTAL
0      1      3        0.15             0.3
1      1      3        0.15             0.3
2      1      4        0.20             0.4
3      2      2        0.10             0.2
4      2      2        0.10             0.2
5      2      6        0.30             0.6
```